# How to divide integers in Oracle SQL to produce floating point numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have just started learning Oracle SQL. I am trying to divide two columns of `numeric` datatype which is same as an integer, I think. I want to create a new column in the table or `float` data type, divide an existing `numeric` column by an integer and put its value into the `float` column. I am using this code for the division and updating part:

```
update Student set AVERAGE = TOTAL/3;
```

Here, `TOTAL` is the `numeric` column and `AVERAGE` is `float`. But when I print the table using:

```
select * from Student;
```

, `AVERAGE` is shown with rounded values of the division. I tried two solutions that I found on the internet:

```
update Student set AVERAGE = (TOTAL*1.00)/3;
```

And:

```
update Student set AVERAGE = cast(TOTAL as float(2))/3;
```

But both are not working. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the output I am getting:

```
 ROLL_NO SNAME                MATHS       CHEM        PHY      TOTAL    AVERAGE
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       101 abcd                    56         68         80        204         70
       102 efgh                    81         78         70        229         80
       103 ijkl                    69         73         78        220         70
       104 mnop                    90         89         92        271         90
       105 qrst                    80         89         79        248         80
```

Comment: Table description?

Comment: Do you really want **floating points**? Or just numeric results with precision to  decimal places?

Comment: I have never seen a case where the [`float`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F579F4B8-EF13-4CAF-9B06-03B076861C41) datatype was needed in Oracle. The documentation states that it is provided for compatibility and recommends that you use `binary_float` or `binary_double` instead. I have never seen a need for those either. Why do you need `float`, specifically?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson can you get decimal numbers in `numeric` as well? I thought `numeric` was the alternate for `Integers`

Comment: @ShantanuShinde Yes, though `numeric` is the alternative term for `number` which is almost always used for any numeric value. Have a read of the documentation section on [data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to understand what `FLOAT` datatype in Oracle means.

> The Oracle `FLOAT` data type is the subtype of the `NUMBER` data type.
>
> Synatx:
>
> FLOAT(p)
>
> p is precision in Binary bits.
>
> Following formula is used to convert between binary and decimal
>   precision: Decimal = 0.30103 * Binary

Now, According to the result you are getting, I think your column (`AVERAGE`) datatype is `FLOAT(1)`. 
If you need more precision then you need to alter your table with more precision value in Binary.

Let's take an example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    f1 FLOAT,
    f2 FLOAT(1),
    f3 FLOAT(4),
    f4 FLOAT(7)
);

INSERT
    INTO
        TEST(
            f1,
            f2,
            f3,
            f4
        )
    VALUES(
        10 / 3,
        10 / 3,
        10 / 3,
        10 / 3
    );

select * from TEST;
```

**Output:**

[image]

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a68053e0dbf4ece535964e963906e947)

If you do not provide any precision then Oracle will take the maximum precision(126 bits 
 --> 37 decimal).

In the above example, the data type of the column f1, f2, f3, and f4 is FLOAT, FLOAT(1), FLOAT(4), and FLOAT(7).

The corresponding precision in decimal digits of the column f1, **f2 <-- (Your case)**, f3 and f4 is 37(126 * 0.30103), **1 (1 * 0.30103) <-- (Your case)**, 2 (4 * 0.30103), and 3 (7 * 0.30103).

**So, Conclusion is** --> alter your table and change the precision of the `AVERAGE` column's `FLOAT` datatype according to your requirement.

Cheers!!

Comment: the precision of 10 is giving 2 decimals. I still don't understand the precision. what does the no.? represent exactly. in most languages, it is just the no. of decimal places.

Comment: Yes, Only in case of FLOAT, precision is in Binary bits. If you want the precision of 3 decimals then you need to provide 3 / 0.30103 = 9.96 ~ 10 as a precision. See f5 in the following [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e96b3e15c0bf33264297a4ae22dca21f) . If still you find an issue then please add the DDL of table and sample data in your question using EDIT option

Answer (score 1):

This is a little long for a comment.

The column `average` is going to be displayed based on the datatype of that column.  Oracle will convert the "numbers" being divided so the result is accurate, I think using the number type.

You can run the following code to see that the division result is always the same:

```
select cast(10 as int) / cast(3 as int),
       cast(10 as numeric) / cast(3 as numeric),
       cast(10 as float) / cast(3 as float)
from dual;
```

So the data type of the operands doesn't make a difference.

On the other hand, the data type of the *result* does.  These produce different results:

```
select cast(10 / 3 as int),
       cast(10 / 3 as float),
       cast(10 / 3 as number),
       cast(10 / 3 as numeric(5, 1))
from dual;
```

Comment: so should I cast the entire result intsead of just the `TOTAL`?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde . . . No, you should fix the data type of `average` so it stores the value as you intend.

Comment: the other answer solved it. the problem was precision of float data type which is in binary in sql but other languages just use numbers

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle the `NUMBER` data type is already a floating point type. It's unusual in that it's a base-10 floating point number type so it's safe to use for calculations involving money, but it's still a floating point type. [Docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313)

It is *possible* to define a NUMBER which holds only integers by defining a subtype or a particular field as having 0 for the scale component, e.g.

```
nInt_value    NUMBER(10,0);
```

or

```
SUBTYPE TEN_DIGIT_INTEGER_TYPE IS NUMBER(10,0);
```

in which case `nInt_value` will only be able to hold whole numbers of 10 digits or less.

Note that SUBTYPE is only available in PL/SQL - in other words, you can't define a SUBTYPE in a PL/SQL module and then use it as a database field. [Docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99934)